# Why are we not getting any data return from our query?

Tags: mysql, group-by

CSMID is in both the CSM_T and Account_T tables, but we want CSMID to be grouped by the CSMID in Account_T table.

It keeps stating "0 rows returned", but not sure why. We loaded the data we are using into both tables already as well.

Below is our query:

```
Select CSMID,Health
From CSM_T, Account_T
Where Health in
    (Select CSMID
    From CSM_T
    Where Health= 'Red')
Group by CSMID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
Select a.CSMID,Health
From CSM_T a inner join Account_T b on a.CSMID=b.CSMID
Where Health= 'Red'
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! This totally worked. I tried inner join but in a different way and it didn't work either, so this totally helps.